# How to download the content of iframe using html unit where the ajax is used?

Tags: iframe, htmlunit

I am going to get the content of iframe. The iframe part contains the table, where some of its information needed to be extracted via the ajax function. How can I get the content of them? Thanks in advance.

According to some private problems, I am so sorry that I just can offer the fake link of URL.

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
//creat a new WebClient object which is equal to browser  
URL url= new URL("http://www.yahoo.com/");  
HtmlPage page=(HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(url);  

java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.apache.http").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE);
webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);  
webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
webClient.getCookieManager().setCookiesEnabled(true);
webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

final HtmlPage startPage =  webClient.getPage("http://www.yahoo.com/");
String text = startPage.asText();

webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(5000);


List<HtmlInlineFrame> anchors4 = (List<HtmlInlineFrame>) startPage.<HtmlInlineFrame>getByXPath("//iframe[@id='contentFrame']");
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(5000);
System.out.println(anchors4.get(0).getTextContent());


List<HtmlDivision> anchors2 = (List<HtmlDivision>) startPage.<HtmlDivision>getByXPath("//div[@class='login_button']");    
anchors2.get(0).click();

List<HtmlInlineFrame> anchors3 = (List<HtmlInlineFrame>) startPage.<HtmlInlineFrame>getByXPath("//iframe[@id='contentFrame']");
webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScriptStartingBefore(5000);
System.out.println("this" + anchors3.get(0).asXml());


List<HtmlTable> htmlTable = (List<HtmlTable>) startPage.<HtmlTable>getByXPath("//table[@class='Result']");
```

Comment: Can you please post the html and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Some coding are provided.

Comment: Does your frame have a `name` attribute?

Comment: Yes, it has. I added according to your method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try by using `FrameWindow`(fot his, you need your `iframe` having a `name` attribute):

```
// ...
startPage = anchors2.get(0).click();

HtmlPage framePage = (HtmlPage) startPage.getFrameByName("your_frame_name").getEnclosedPage();
System.out.println("The content that you need: " + framePage.asXml());
```

Comment: Thank you. It worked but still need some examinations.

Comment: If there are elements missing, try to enable javascript.

Comment: You rescue me. Thanks very much. I forgot to enable the javascript function.

Comment: I just encounter a 500 Internal Server Error, when it prints the xml. Do you know what this error comes from?

Comment: It might me some script that is not executed completely. It's difficult to tell without seeing the html of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your comments.